# X + Y sorting in n dimension

Tags: algorithms, sorting

I was wondering if there is an approach to sort the sums of k integers in a set of n integers; which would be a generalization of the x + y sorting problem.

Or even without generating the whole set of k sums, would it be possible to generate de m largest k sums in a set of n non negative integers?

Comment: Please include the `x + y sorting problem` in your question: Your question initially states *in a set of n integers* - one set?! - while at least one variant called *x + y sorting* has (x, y) from separate, finite sets X&Y, respectively. The last problem doesn't look too hard: What has been your best try so far?

Comment: As the $X+Y$ sorting problem is not known to have a faster solution than $n^2\log n$, which essentially means "brute force", we can doubt that there is an approach for the generalization.